# Convertion of various form of int slices

Tags: go

Let's assume I have these types

```
type MyInt int
type Ints []int
type MyInts []MyInt
```

Using these types I define some variables

```
var is []int
var ints Ints
var myInts MyInts
```

The variables `is` and `ints` have different type, however the compiler happily compiles this line

```
is = ints
```

Similarly `is` and `myInts` have different types, but in this case the following line is not compiled because the types of the variables are different

```
is = myInts
```

So, why in the first case the difference of types does not stop comlilation, while in the second case it does stop it?

Here a simple [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/1R8heUsfFTL) that reproduces the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the [conditions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) for a valid assignment is the following:

> `V` and `T` have identical **underlying** types but are not type parameters and **at least one** of V or T is **not a named type**.

---

The `is` variable's type `[]int` is an **unnamed** type, it's **underlying** type is identical to itself, i.e. `[]int`. The type of `ints` variable, i.e. `Ints`, is a **named** type, it's **underlying** type `[]int`.

Hence the assignment `is = ints` is valid.

---

The `myInts` variable's type `MyInts` is a **named** type, it's **underlying** type is `[]MyInt`. Type `[]MyInt` is **not identical** to `[]int`.

Hence the assignment `is = myInts` is not valid.